# Laravel - Generating composer.json and artisan files?

Tags: composer-php, laravel-5

I downlaod composer.phar and move to /usr/local/bin/ directory as composer, then I download laravel with

> composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"

After I linked laravel to /usr/local/bin/ , I run "laravel new test" and I get

> Composer could not find a composer.json file in /home/user/test
>   To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the http://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section

So laravel doesn't generate composer.json and artisan files
Can you help why?

**Edit**
I was going to format PC for some reasons. After I had formatted PC, I did above steps again and it worked.

> laravel new hello

is working now

Answer (score 0):

you should link your laravel to \composer\vendor\bin folder. After downloading the laravel installer run this command

```
export PATH="$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin"
```

and then run your laravel command.

Comment: I also try that not working now, I'am using "composer create-project laravel/laravel ProjectName --prefer-dist" instead of "laravel new ProjectName"

Answer (score -1):

If you want to install Laravel at current folder. You don't use `global`:

```
composer require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
```